# WebEx webmeeting hangs at 64%

Tags: java

Whenever I try to open webmeeting through AT&T WebEx, it loads till 64% and then hangs.The AT&T FAQs say that Linux machines can host webmeetings as long as you have java installed.
I have installed the latest `sun-java-jre` from Sun (Oracle) and have removed `openjdk` & `icedtea` altogether.

Has anyone else tried this? Any suggestions on fixing it?

Comment: btw: webex webmeeting works nicely on RHEL 5.5 with FF 3.0, so there must be problem with ubuntu packages or firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question can be closed. it is a problem with AT&T webex . I spoke to their technical support . They told me , the support for Linux is till firefox 3.0