# Alternative for Remedy client, AT&T webex and MS Office Communicator?

Tags: software-recommendation, office-communicator

Part two of my question.
 I am trying to replace my Windows 7 system with a working Ubuntu system but I am running into issues with several software being used at work. Could anyone please advise alternatives for the following software / tools?

1. Remedy client
2. AT&T webex ( currently works only
   with RHEL 5.1 & lower + FF 3.0 &
   lower)
3. MS Office Communicator

Comment: AT&T WebEx [seems to work for FF3 only](http://askubuntu.com/q/27966/6969). For those who do not know Remedy client, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AR_System_User).

Comment: ya, and does not work with ubuntu 10.10 + FF3.0! How wierd!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an Idea on Ubuntu Brainstorm for AT&T WebEx, [Idea #7487: Screen Sharing - Remote Meetings Application like WebEx](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/7487/) which was closed as duplicate of [Idea #17102: Easy screen-sharing and audio-chat for instant messengers](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/17102/) .

They recommend Vino or Empathy. Note that these software are most likely not compatible with AT&T WebEx.

I am afraid that the software used at work cannot be fully replaced by Ubuntu if you need compatibility between the programs used by you and your company. If you need to run certain Windows applications in Ubuntu, you could try [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) or a virtual machine like [VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox). Another solution would be a dualboot system, Windows for your job and Ubuntu for daily usage.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to WebEx is RHUB. Its web conferencing servers works well and best part is, it has no download of any kind.

Comment: It would be better if you also included instructions on how to install it here than just mentioning it.